# Is there a way to make this statement using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have been trying in many ways but my knowledge is not good enough XD

```
DB::select ('SELECT c.`id_client`, UPPER (c.`name`) AS `name`, '
    . 'c.`telephone`, MATCH (c.`name`) AGAINST ( ? ) AS `match` '
    . 'FROM client c '
    . 'WHERE MATCH (c.`name`) AGAINST ( ? ) '
    . 'HAVING `match` > 5.2 ORDER BY `match` DESC LIMIT 10', array ($name, $name));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done with Eloquent, perhaps [Fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) instead?

```
$results = DB::table('client')
    ->select(array(
        'id_client', 'name', 'telephone',
        DB::raw("MATCH(name) AGAINST (?) AS match")
    ))
    ->whereRaw("MATCH (name) AGAINST(?)")
    ->having('match', '>', 5.2)
    ->orderBy('match','desc')
    ->limit(10);
```

There will probably be some typos there, but this **should** point you in the right direction.

Fixed some typos.

**Update**:
You can try using "match against" as shown in the 2 examples below. Not sure if either works as I haven't tested, but give both a try -- the second looks cleaner:

```
->where(DB::raw('MATCH(`some_field`)'),'AGAINST',DB::raw('("bar")'))
```

OR

```
->whereRaw('MATCH (some_field) AGAINST("bar")')
```

Just replace the bar with something you wish to match against. Hope that helps.

Comment: well, I wanted to say Query builder as  you said jeje, lets test it :)

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, how or where do I replace the question mark?